# Detect new video and audio inputs

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, audio, video

I want to create application where I can record video with audio and save it to disk.
When application start I detect all video and audio sources and show this list on the UI.
But when I disconnect one of webcams (or unplug mic), this device still remain in list.

How I can get notifications of device connect/disconnect, both for video devices(USB) and audio devices(jack 3.5).

Thank you.

WBR
Maxim

Comment: some code here would help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find some useful tips in this other question, here [IOKit device adding/removal notifications - only fire once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628195/iokit-device-adding-removal-notifications-only-fire-once/16488337#16488337)

I also have an example of an app that uses the IOKit framework to detect adding and removing USB devices on my github account here: https://github.com/tjarratt/Panic-Button

Baring that, the apple developer site has a lot of documentation on using USB devices:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/devicedrivers/conceptual/USBBook/USBDeviceInterfaces/USBDevInterfaces.html

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
I will check all what you recommend. As I can see whole information what you give this for USB devices and what about jack 3.5 for mics. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with using the 3.5" jack for mics and other audio devices, but I think the Core Audio framework will probably be of use there.

Comment: Hey @kroumvud did you ever find a solution for this? I'm actually finding that I'm working on a small art project involving audio inputs and I was curious if you ever solved this...

Comment: Hey @tjarratt

sorry for late response, unfortunately I don't found any solution for now. :(

May I see your art project somewhere?